# Rails: ENV variable failure outputs double string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, environment-variables, rake

I have a rake task that requires 3 of my environment variables. 2 of them pass fine but one keeps outputting inside a double-string causing an error.

Here is a what I have in my `.bash_profile`

```
export FG_PASSWORD=“mysecret”
export FG_USERNAME=“username@secret.com”
export FG_DOMAIN=“secret”
```

In Rails I setup them up here..

**config/initializers/api.rb**

```
FG_PASSWORD = ENV["FG_PASSWORD"]
FG_USERNAME = ENV["FG_USERNAME"]
FG_DOMAIN = ENV["FG_DOMAIN"]
```

My rake task...

**lib/rake/upload_files.rake**

```
namespace :upload_files do
    task :upload_base => :environment do
        c = Foldergrid::Connection.new(FG_PASSWORD, FG_USERNAME, FG_DOMAIN)
        p FG_DOMAIN

        ....some code...
    end
end
```

The culprit is the `FG_DOMAIN`. It works when hard-coded. The `p FG_DOMAIN` line outputs the variable as `""secret""` hence the double-string.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the export statements.  They should look like:

```
export FG_PASSWORD=mysecret
export FG_USERNAME=username@secret.com
export FG_DOMAIN=secret
```

Comment: Just tried it and still doesn't work. `FG_DOMAIN` still outputs as double-string.